Use Subset of Monitors in an RDP Session Initiated Through Gateway
So I've seen this article on using a subset of monitors in an RDP session. In my case, I have to log in through a gateway in my browser before clicking a link to open "Pulse Secure" which connects me to my host through what looks like a standard Windows RDP session. Can I overwrite the default settings that the RDP session opens up through that gateway so I can apply the selectedmonitors:s: command?
As far as I can tell, the gateway website has options in the UI that are word-for-word copies of the Windows Remote Desktop Connection Configuration app, so I'm guessing that the options must be somehow being pulled from the website and then passed along to Windows when "Pulse Secure" is launched.

If they are word-for-word copies, have you just tried adding the arguments? Also, I'm guessing this system is managed by an employer or contracting agency: have you tried reaching out to them to see if they allow/support this sort of thing?

@music2myear The only available option is "Use All My Monitors", just like the Windows RDP options. That's why the trick in the article is to open up the RDP file in something like notepad and add the selectedmonitors:s:X,Y argument.

Am I correct to assume the gateway/tool you're using doesn't have a config file you can edit? And what about the second part of my earlier question?

@music2myear Not as far as I can tell, I've snooped around the %appdata% directory and haven't seen anything. I have not tried contacting IT, but onsite we do use the standard Windows RDP where we save/edit the RDP configurations. Ultimately, I'll either contact IT or just deal with using 3 monitors.

I’m voting to close this question because this question is about corporate or other organizational IT issues and should be referred to designated IT support staff.
